# Sendgrid Substitutions Tags

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sendgrid, substitution, transactional-email

I want to send a notification email in my application and I am trying to use sendgrid. My application is writtin in CoffeeScript.

```
enter code here 
from_address = 'noreply@example.co'
subject = 'This Is The Subject'
html_body = '<table style="font-family: verdana, tahoma, sans-serif; color: #000;">
          <tr> <td>
          <h2>Hello,</h2> <p>Hello!!</p>
                          <p>%%name%% %%surname%% send you a message</p>
          </table>'
sendgrid = require('sendgrid')(api_key)
Email = sendgrid.Email
email = new Email(
  to: to_address
  from: from_address
  subject: subject
  text: text_body
  html: html_body)

recipients = [
  'example1@example.com'
  'example2@example.com'
]
i = 0
while i < recipients.length
  email.addTo recipients[i]
  i++

substitutions = {
  "%%name%%": [
    "name1",
    "name2"
  ],
  "%%surname%%": [
     "surname1",
     "surname2"
  ]
}

for tag in substitutions
  email.addSubstitution(tag, substitutions[tag])

email.setFilters({
  "templates": {
    "settings": {
      "enable": "1",
       "template_id": "XXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX"
   }
 }
})


sendgrid.send email, (err, json) ->
  if err
    return console.log(err)
  console.log json
return
```

When I execute the code send my the email to the emails address. But the message is:

Hello!!

%%name%% %%surname%% send you a message.

The substitution doesn't work. I try changing %% for %,- and #. But any ot those seems to work. Also I try using setSections.

**Update**

This is the sendgrid object i am sending.

```
{ to: [ 'example1@example.com', 'example2@example.com' ],
  from: 'noreply@example.co',
  smtpapi: 
   { version: '1.2.0',
     header: 
      { to: [],
        sub: {},
        unique_args: {},
        category: [Object],
        section: {},
        filters: [Object],
        send_at: '',
        send_each_at: [],
        asm_group_id: {},
        ip_pool: '' } },
  subject: 'This Is The Subject',
  text: 'Hello!\n\nThis is a test message from SendGrid. We have sent this to you because you requested a test message be sent from your account.\n\n This is a link to google.com: http://www.google.com\n This is a link to apple.com: http://www.apple.com\n This is a link to sendgrid.com: http://www.sendgrid.com\n\n Thank you for reading this test message.\n\nLove,\nYour friends at SendGrid',
  html: '<table style="font-family: verdana, tahoma, sans-serif; color: #000;"> <tr> <td> <h2>Hello,</h2> <p>Hello!!</p> <p>%%name%% %%surname%% send you a message</p> </table>',
  bcc: [],
  cc: [],
  replyto: '',
  date: '',
  headers: {},
  toname: undefined,
  fromname: undefined,
  files: [] }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you print out what the sendgrid object ends up looking like? It seems like you're not adding the substitutions in the `x-smtpapi` header properly, but seeing the full thing would be helpful

Comment: Hi, @jacobmovingfwd I added the sendgrid object just before using the sendgrid.send method. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nobody knows which could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question because already found the problem.

The problem was not related with Sendgrid but with coffeeScript. In one of my statement I use this:

```
for tag in substitutions
  email.addSubstitution(tag, substitutions[tag])
```

I try here to add to the email object the substitutions tag. But the debuging my code I found that the loop was not iterating over the substitution variable. So any tag was added to the email object.

I've changed the previous code for this one:

```
Object.keys(substitutions).forEach((tag)->
  email.addSubstitution(tag, sub[tag])
  return
```

And with this change the substitutions tags was added to the email object.